# What does "nesting mothers" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning

> “Just get past them, I think,” said Charlie. “We'll be on hand if it gets nasty, Extinguishing Spells at the ready. They wanted **nesting mothers**, I don't know why…but I tell you this, I don't envy the one who gets the Horntail. Vicious thing. Its back end's as dangerous as its front, look.”

I couldn't find any reference about "nesting mothers" anywhere. What does it mean?

Comment: You're not showing much ingenuity here. Any dictionary could have told you this.  So I'm not sure what you mean by "couldn't find any reference".

Comment: I believe you know what "mothers" means. So the thing to search for is therefore "nesting", not "nesting mothers". Only once you've done that, found it, and it still doesn't make sense, should you consider the possibility that those two words together may mean something different than just the separate meanings of those two words.

Comment: I agree with the comment made by @Tᴚoɯɐuo here. At the very least, tell us where and how you looked. Did you use Google? If so, what was your search query? (If it was a fruitless search, you could save some of us some time by keeping us from doing the same lookups. "I couldn't fine any reference anywhere" doesn't help us much.)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Dan is reading the Harry Potter series of books at the moment and his questions are related to this.

In the Potter books, as part of the TriWizard Tournament, competitors have to attempt to retrieve an object from a dragon. Presuming that dragons in the the Potter books are egg laying reptiles, then "Nesting Mothers" relates to female dragons with clutches of eggs.

The Oxford Dictionary definition of [nesting](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/nesting):

> ADJECTIVE
>
> 1(of a bird or other animal) building or occupying a nest.
>   ‘do not disturb nesting birds’

Presumably a mother dragon's instinct to protect its eggs will mean it guards the prize as if it were part of its clutch.

The use of nesting in pregnant humans is metaphorical, our species does not literally create a nest.

Answer (score 2):

In this case, *Harry Potter*, **nesting mothers** implies the dragons guarding their eggs.

According to AmericanPregnancy.org:

> You might wake up one morning feeling energetic and wanting to clean and organize your entire house. This urge to clean and organize is known as **nesting**.

Well, just keep it in mind, for now.

**Nesting** indicates trait of caring. The instinct of nest-building is found in many animals during pregnancy, as to protect their upcoming babies from dangers like predators.

You just need to google "nesting". :-)

Comment: This is a good general answer, but it is not fully correct in the specific context, as it refers to dragons guarding their nest with eggs in it.